# JBoss Forge - How to setup arquillian

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I used JBoss 7 and JBoss Forge 1.x a while ago and was quite happy with the setup. Now I want to use the latest 2.8 release with JBoss 8.1 and can't even setup Arquillian.

Running:

```
forge install-plugin arquillian
```

gives

```
forge: unrecognized option: 'install-plugin'
```

Following the various how to's din't help since most of them seem to be made for older Arquillian and JBoss releases.

```
forge --install arquillian
```

gives

```
downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/forge/addon/arquillian/maven-   metadata.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Artifact version found for   org.jboss.forge.addon:arquillian
```

Are there any recent descriptions on how to setup arquillian using forge ?

Answer (score 6):

To install the Arquillian addon, you need to run the following command:

```
addon-install-from-git --url https://github.com/forge/plugin-arquillian.git --coordinate org.arquillian.forge:arquillian-addon --ref forge2
```

More info here: http://forge.jboss.org/addon/org.arquillian.forge:arquillian-addon

Comment: Using Forge 3 this command will not work without the `--ref forge2`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You can also use addon-install-from-git --url https://github.com/forge/addon-arquillian.git

Comment: does not work even though it tells you it did install successfully. `list-addons` will not list the addon without using your whole command and thus also not recognize any commands from the addon.

Comment: Any stacktrace? Feel free to open an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FORGEPLUGINS